# A parallel for Django's @never_cache in Tornado

Tags: http-headers, tornado, http-caching

What would be the canonical way to implement a parallel of Django's `@never_cache` for Tornado's `RequestHandler.get()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's enough to override `RequestHandler.compute_etag()` to return `None`? As in:

```
class BaseHandler(RequestHandler):

    def compute_etag(self):
        return None
```

This seems to do the trick in local development.